# Identify web socket client

Tags: javascript, c#, php, websocket

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a small issue I have, I am trying to identify each client with the Fleck web sockets library in .NET and with PHP

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['web_socket_username_submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['web_socket_username'] = $_POST['web_socket_username'];
    header("location: ");
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['web_socket_username'])) {
    echo 'You need to select a username before continuing, this username will stick with you untill you clean your cache.<br>';
    echo '<form name="webSocketUsernameForm" method="post">';
    echo '';
    echo '<input type="text" name="web_socket_username" placeholder="Username...">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="web_socket_username_submit" value="Continue">';
    echo '</form>';
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>websocket client</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var start = function () {
            var inc = document.getElementById('incomming');
            var wsImpl = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
            var form = document.getElementById('sendForm');
            var input = document.getElementById('sendText');

            inc.innerHTML += "connecting to server ..<br/>";
            // create a new websocket and connect
            window.ws = new wsImpl('ws://localhost:8181/');
            // when data is comming from the server, this metod is called
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                inc.innerHTML += "Emulator: " + evt.data + '<br/>';
            };
            // when the connection is established, this method is called
            ws.onopen = function () {
                inc.innerHTML += 'Emulator accepted your connection.<br/>';
            };
            // when the connection is closed, this method is called
            ws.onclose = function () {
                inc.innerHTML += 'Emulator closed the connection.<br/>';
            }

            form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var val = input.value;
                ws.send(val);
                input.value = "";
            });

        }
        window.onload = start;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="sendForm">
        <input id="sendText" placeholder="Text to send" />
    </form>
    <pre id="incomming"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSockets_Testing
{
    using Fleck;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
            var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
            var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://127.0.0.1:8181");
            server.Start(socket =>
            {
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Open!");
                    allSockets.Add(socket);
                };
                socket.OnClose = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Close!");
                    allSockets.Remove(socket);
                };
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("You: " + message));
                };
            });


            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input != "exit")
            {
                foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
                {
                    socket.Send(input);
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I identify a client without it being spoofed who it is?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve this is to use socket.ConnectionInfo.Id which returns a unique GUID per socket.